# How to pattern match a variable length tuple

Tags: f#

I have a few utility functions like this that return different length tuples:

```
let get1And2Of4(v1, v2, v3, v4) = v1, v2
let get1And2And3Of4(v1, v2, v3, v4) = v1, v2, v3
```

I'd like to be able to pattern match on a variable and return the appropriate utility function.

For example,

```
let bar = 
     match foo with
     | "A" -> get1And2Of4
     | "B" -> get1And2And3Of4
```

However, the compiler complains because the length of the tuples are different. Reading [Variable length tuples in f#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135580/variable-length-tuples-in-f) and [Elegant pattern matching on nested tuples of arbitrary length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38906758/elegant-pattern-matching-on-nested-tuples-of-arbitrary-length) explains that this isn't really possible.

Are there any other options to achieve this given that I need to work with tuples and not lists?

Comment: In `myFrame |> Series.mapValues (Stats.levelMean myLvlFun) `, please indicate the types of `myFrame`, `Series.mapValues`, and `Stats.levelMean`. That will make clear the required type of `myLvlFun`.

Comment: Those are from the Deedle library http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/Deedle but i'll update the question to include.

Comment: You can't do that. Could you use a list as the return type of myLvlFun, instead of tuples?

Comment: From the type signatures, you have a `Series<(int * string * string * int),float>`, and want to change the second parameter using `mapValues`, so you need to give it a function `float -> b` in order to get a `Series<(int * string * string * int),float>` in the end. Is this correct? You are not close to giving it a `float -> b` so I could be wrong. We have very little info to guess what you are trying to do, as you have given a method which doesn't work, but the definition of the problem is given by a line of code that also doesn't make sense. It's hard to guess what your question is.

Comment: Yes I think i worded this question incorrectly now that I’ve read up more. The real question is how can you write a function that can return a variable length tuple. The answer is you can’t so what’s the best alternative to keep this DRY

Comment: This is not becoming any closer to being an intelligible question unfortunately. "What's the best alternative to keep this" is the question, but the thing for which an alternative is sought doesn't exist, so this should be "what is the best way to do this", but you haven't said what "this" is.

Comment: Rewrote question.

Comment: You want `bar ` to return two- or three-part tuple. Let's imagine that's done. Could you specify what you would like to do with that value next? What operations would you like to perform on it given you're not interested in list-style operations, but in tuple-style ones? You won't be able to do eg. `bar.Third` if `bar` does not necessarily contain a `Third` component.

Comment: @JSparrow I'm working with a third party library called [Deedle](https://bluemountaincapital.github.io/Deedle/). It requires passing in a tuple you want to return stats at a particular level of your frame -- http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/Deedle/stats.html#Multi-level-indexed-statistics. 

So i'd like to be able to something like `|> Series.mapValues (Stats.levelMedian bar)` where bar is the utility function.

Answer (score 1):

The only practicable, type-safe way I can imagine would be to spell it all out explicitly and wrap the functions as individual cases in a discriminated union. This is obviously awkward; on the plus side it helps you to keep track of the various type parameters that are involved, since in the end all code paths will need to return the same type.

```
type WhateverYouFeelNamingTheDU<'a,'b,'c,'d> =
| Get1And2Of4 of ('a * 'b * 'c * 'd -> 'a * 'b)
| Get1And2And3Of4 of ('a * 'b * 'c * 'd -> 'a * 'b * 'c)
let get1And2Of4 = Get1And2Of4(fun (v1, v2, _, _) -> v1, v2)
let get1And2And3Of4 = Get1And2And3Of4(fun (v1, v2, v3, _) -> v1, v2, v3)

match "foo" with
| "A" -> get1And2Of4
| _ -> get1And2And3Of4
|> function
| Get1And2Of4 f42 -> f42 (1,2,"a","b") |> string
| Get1And2And3Of4 f43 -> f43 (3,4,"c","d") |> string
// val it : string = "(3, 4, c)"
```

Comment: I'm still relatively new to F#. If possible, can you explain what's happening after the match? It looks like you are matching the return type to a new function and then executing that. Is that correct?

Comment: Since i'm trying to pass the resulting variable length tuple on to another function (the function doesn't care about the tuple length, it just needs to be a tuple) forcing the return type to string doesn't work. It needs to be a tuple.

Comment: @StringerBell If you don't play any tricks with reflection, you cannot have a function which doesn't care about the tuple length, since for a f# function taking a tuple the length is fixed and an innate part of its signature. You may be thinking about [`params[]`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params), a method with a variable number of arguments, but that's an array under the hood. Now, discriminated unions in f# serve as sum types with which you could separate a 2-tuple from a 3-tuple and hand them on accordingly in their respective match clauses.

Comment: I'm using Deedle and it has this [function](https://github.com/fslaborg/Deedle/blob/6472ef26803f2d333533d9c7da57216eafc9e0b3/src/Deedle/FrameModule.fs#L1589) that lets's me pass in a variable length tuple as far as I can tell...at the end of the day I'm trying to pass in any of my utility functions as the levelSel parameter.